# Represent a 3d vector as a single numerical value

Tags: numpy, opencv, math

Is it possible to convert a 3d vector representing a colour into a single numerical value (*x*)? Something ideally that is a float value between 0 and 1. Math's is not my strong suit at all so from my googling I think I either need to use vectorization or convert the value to a tensor to achieve my objective. Would that be correct?

An example of what I am trying to achieve is:

```
labColour = (112, 48, 0)
labAsFloat = colour_to_float(luvColour, cspace='LAB')
print(labAsFloat) # outputs something like 0.74673543

def colour_to_float(colour, cspace):
    return ??? somehow vectorise??
```

Comment: 3 bytes can be converted into an int which can be converted into a float (normalized to [0,1] if you want), but the resulting float would be somewhat arbitrarily linked to the color. What are you trying to achieve? This seems like it might be an XY problem.

Comment: what is `cspace` ?

Comment: @Layla cspace is the color space 'LAB' in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure I understand your question correctly. If the objective is merely a unique floating number representation then this might work.

```
def colour_to_float(colour):
    int_arr = list(colour)
    int_arr.append(0)
    data_bytes = np.array(int_arr, dtype=np.uint8)

    return (data_bytes.view(dtype=np.float32))[0]

def float_to_colour(num):
    return np.array([num], dtype=np.float32).view(dtype=np.uint8)[:3].tolist()
```

Results:

```
labColour = (230, 140, 50)
f = colour_to_float(labColour)
print(f)
4.64232e-39
    
lab = float_to_colour(f)
print(lab)
[230, 140, 50]
```